# Fatal Error- Require_once

Tags: php, xampp

I am getting the following error:

> Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc\public\views\home\init.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc\public\index.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc\public\views\home\init.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc\public\index.php on line 3

In Index.php, my code is

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '\views\home\init.php';
$app= new app;
?>
```

In init.php, my code is

```
<?php require_once __DIR__ . '\core\app.php';
 require_once  __DIR__ . '\core\controller.php';
```

In controller.php:

```
<?php
class controller
{
}
?>
```

In app.php

```
<?php
class app
{
public function _construct() 
{
    echo 'now what';
}
}
?>
```

My folder paths are:

> htdocs\mvc\app\views\home\init.php
>
> htdocs\mvc\app\core\app.php & controller.php
>
> htdocs\mvc\public\index.php

Anybody please help? i have tried require_once (_DIR . ""); as well but not working.

Comment: there has to be a problem with the file path. right now you're pointing to a file in a views directory in the same place as index.php.. is this correct?

Comment: It seems that your `index.php` is located at `public/` folder, while your required file `views/home/init.php` is located at `app/` folder. So, try `require '../app/views/home/init.php';` If it doesn't work, you can try `realpath (__FILE__.'../app');` to get your `app/` folder's realpath name.

Comment: index.php is in mvc/public. View path is mvc/app/views

Comment: @Chu i have tried it also but its not working as well. Both, require & require_once

Comment: @Ayaz Oh, I'm sorry. It's  `../../views/home/init.php`, I've forgot another `..`

Comment: I recommend you to use namespaces and psr-4 autoloader http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/. Or just switch to using composer. With this option you will never get knocked out by such problems again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

First do `echo` for the file path in `index.php` file like -

```
echo __DIR__ . '/views/home/init.php';
```

And then check whether the path is correct or not. If not, then change it accordingly and then use the path in `require_once`.

Comment: this is what i get after putting echo. It seems path is correct: C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc\public/views/home/init.php
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc\public\index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc\public\index.php on line 5

Comment: Use same `__DIR__`  for requiring `app.php` and `controller.php`. Check the file permission too.

Comment: How to check file permission? also should i use 
accept
Try this:

First do echo for the file path in index.php file like -

echo __DIR__ . '/views/home/init.php';  & require_once'views/home/init.php';  together in code or just after checking the path remove _DIR_ and then use require_once

Comment: `echo __DIR__ . '/views/home/init.php';` this one is for testing only. Finally, you have to write your code like `require_once __DIR__ . '/views/home/init.php';` and use __DIR__ for other required lines.

Comment: after putting __DIR__ in all three codes: Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc\publicviews/home/init.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc\public\index.php on line 3
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc\publicviews/home/init.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc\public\index.php on line 3

Comment: You missed one `/` I guess. As in your error section, you mentioned `C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc\publicviews/home/init.php`. See there is no `/` between `public` and `views`. Check your code again.

Comment: i have tried / & \ both now the error is: Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc\public\views\home\init.php)

Comment: edited \ & / in require_once __DIR__ . '\views\home\init.php'; just changing  \ or / in error

Comment: The code works perfectly for me without `require_once` issue. Just one thing is in `app.php`, the code should be `public function __construct() ` i.e. 2 underscore before `construct`. `__construct()`. Otherwise everything works well for me. Please check your code and check the file permission. You can provide 775 file permission to those required files.

Comment: i m using windows and i have setup full permissions in security tab to files except special permission tab which is only uncheked.

Comment: Its working - what i have done is i have changed the folders places and bring out all the folders. So the main folder is mvc and all other sub folders to this folder. No any subfolder to other subfolder

Answer (score 0):

You can also test the permission of directory and file itself. There could be an issue of executing file if permission is read only.

Comment: i have made a sample project in localhost xampp some days ago and there were no problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

restore the index.php file in your public folder.... the error will clear out.

Comment: Why do you think so? There's an accepted answer using another way

Comment: i had the same issue and that was what worked for me... i found out i deleted the index.php file in the public folder, restoring the file clears out the error.

Answer (score 0):

Put index.php file in your public folder.... the error will clear out.

tested and verified